# populating gridview with custom button android

Tags: java, android, gridview

I would like to have a grid view be populated with a custom button I created, the problem is I do not know how this adapter works.

This is what I am trying to achieve

[image]

This is my custom button.java

```
    public class Items extends Button {
        private final static int WIDTH_PADDING = 10;
        private final static int HEIGHT_PADDING = 10;
        private final String label;
        private final String name;
        private final double price;

        public Items(Context context, String name, double price) {
            super(context);
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
            this.label = name;

            setHeight(100);
            setWidth(100);
            setFocusable(true);
            setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eef771"));
            setClickable(true);
        }

        protected void onFocusChanged(boolean gainFocus, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
            super.onFocusChanged(gainFocus, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
            if(gainFocus == true) {
                this.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ced662"));
            } else {
                this.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eef771"));
            }

        }

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            Paint textPaint = new Paint();
            textPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#f4426e"));
            canvas.drawText(label + " (P" + price + ")", (WIDTH_PADDING / 2), (HEIG

HT_PADDING / 2,  textPaint);
    }
}
```

and my adapter still looks like this :

```
public class ItemsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;

    public ItemsAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My question : I would like to be able to add a custom button whenever I want to the adapter, do I use an arrayList here? how do I return that arrayList so my gridView will be populated?

I am new to android so I do not know how these things work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to first read this [Android developer topic](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview). You should use the RecyclerView component for creating this screen because it's more optimised and more improved then regular ListView. After you read this Android developer topic, you can go through this [blog post](https://androidteachers.com/android/building-list-and-grid-layout-with-recyclerview-in-android/). There is an example of how to do this kind of screen as you presented in your picture. But be sure to get full knowledge of how does this RecyclerView.Adapter works and how is related to RecyclerView.ViewHolder object.

Comment: No. It has to be a grid, like a table, not a list.

Comment: You can achieve grid look with a RecyclerView. You need to set correct LayoutManager to RecyclerView like this:
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager( nee GridLayoutManager(this, 3))

3 number is the number of columns. Check Blog post at the end.